# Mapping joined query result into Eloquent model

Tags: sql, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I have following database schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE `languages` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `code` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `latin_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        `local_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        UNIQUE KEY `languages_code_unique` (`code`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    CREATE TABLE `films` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    CREATE TABLE `films_downloads` (
        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `film_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
        KEY `films_downloads_film_id_foreign` (`film_id`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    CREATE TABLE `films_downloads_langs` (
        `download_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        `language_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`download_id`,`language_id`),
        KEY `films_downloads_langs_language_id_foreign` (`language_id`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I would get all Languages by film for films list and use it next like

```
    foreach ($films as $film) $film->languages;
```

SQL query and following code in Laravel allow me get what I want, but 
in flat array.

```
    $q = DB::table('films)
        ->select('languages.latin_name', 'films.id as film_id')
        ->join('films_downloads', 'films.id', '=', 'films_downloads.app_id')
        ->join('films_downloads_langs', 'films_downloads.id', '=', 'films_downloads_langs.download_id')
        ->join('languages', 'languages.id', '=', 'films_downloads_langs.language_id')
        ->whereIn('films_downloads.film_id', $films_ids)
        ->groupBy('languages.id' ,'films_downloads.app_id')
        ->get();
```

I would nested arrays / collections / models (prefer), with grouping repeating languages in mysql for multiple films at one query. **How I can fill Film models collection by languages collections?**